# Python PIL: Image.convert() mode "L" to "1" - how to change the value 127

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, rgb, image-conversion

I have an image with only shades of gray and I need to convert it to only black and white ("1") but if I just use:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("img.jpg")
result = img.convert("1")
img.save("result.jpg")
```

pixels with values above 127 convert to white. Is there a way to change this border, for example to 220 so only the lightest pixels will be shown? Thank you

Comment: Can you include the image in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can most simply use the `Image.point()` method to threshold on a different value.

Let's make a 256x256 pixel linear gradient:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.linear_gradient("L")
im.save('a.png')
```

[image]

Now threshold all values above 200 to white, and others to black:

```
thresh200 = im.point(lambda i:255 if i>200 else 0)
thresh200.convert('L').save('b.png')
```

I added a thin red border around it so  you can see the threshold is not at the middle (i.e. 127) but rather at 200, regardless of whether you are viewing on a light or dark background:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Check the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html) out.
You need to use the "dither" argument for your usecase.